# DiskRef disappears while enumerating disks in callback method

Tags: objective-c, diskarbitration

I have used the DiskArbitration classes from the project [Disk-Arbitrator](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator) on GitHub in a project I'm working on.

I am mounting/unmounting OS X Installer Disk Images via `hdiutil` and sometimes the callback method defined for `DARegisterDiskDescriptionChangedCallback` crashes as the disk list is mutated while enumerating, and then that the diskref that get's passed becomes `NULL`.

Here is the function that get's called for the callback:

```
DARegisterDiskDescriptionChangedCallback(session, matching, NULL, DiskDescriptionChangedCallback, (__bridge void *)([NBCDisk class]));

...

void DiskDescriptionChangedCallback(DADiskRef diskRef, CFArrayRef keys, void *context) {
#pragma unused(keys)
    if (context != (__bridge void *)([NBCDisk class])) return;

    NSSet *uniqueDisksCopy = [uniqueDisks copy];
    for ( NBCDisk *disk in uniqueDisksCopy ) {
        if ( CFHash(diskRef) == [disk hash] ) {
            CFDictionaryRef desc = DADiskCopyDescription(diskRef);
            disk.diskDescription = desc;
            CFRelease(desc);

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:DADiskDidChangeNotification object:disk];
        }
    }
}
```

I solved the problem with being mutated while enumerating by making a copy and enumerate on that.

BUT, this code sometimes crash with: `"*** CFHash() called with NULL ***"`

And that is because the disk has disappeared and the `diskRef` probably has been deallocated.

So, I need some tips here. I wanted to try and make a copy of the `diskRef`, and tried that by doing this:

```
DADiskRef diskRefCopy = diskRef;
```

But that did not work either. Is there another way to make a copy? Or is there another way altogether I should approach this.

Comment: When disk disappeared, make sure that `diskRef` is removed from `uniqueDisks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, I need some tips here. I wanted to try and make a copy of the
>   diskRef, and tried that by doing this:
>
> `DADiskRef diskRefCopy = diskRef;`

Since you're interacting with Core Foundation; use -

```
CFRetain(diskRef);
```

Also, have a look at following reference in [Disk-Arbitrator](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator) project, File is Disk.m at line [#80](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator/blob/master/Source/Disk.m#L80):

```
disk = CFRetain(diskRef);
```

And line [#75](https://github.com/aburgh/Disk-Arbitrator/blob/master/Source/Disk.m#L75):

```
return [uniqueDisk retain];
```

---

I hope it helps! BTW taking copy is not needed `NSSet *uniqueDisksCopy = [uniqueDisks copy];`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this helped me to find the issue I was having.